# repaint the components in extJS

Tags: extjs

I need to do next: There are a few buttons. Pressing any of the buttons change forme state, so  some of the buttoms become invisible. 
I wrote the following code

```
Loyalty.company.CompanyEditForm = Ext.extend(Loyalty.tools.AdvancedForm,
    {
        defaultConfig:{
            ......
            currentState: 'READONLY'
            // EDIT, CREATE, CREATE_EDIT
        },


        constructor:function (config) {
            Ext.apply(config, this.defaultConfig);
            config['owner'] = this;
            config['items'] = [];
            config['items'] = this.createItems(config);
            config['buttons'] = this.createButtons(config);
            Loyalty.company.CompanyEditForm.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
            this.loadCompany(config['jsonCompany']);
            this.renderingView(config);// here it's ok
        },

....

        renderingView:function (config){
           if (config.currentState == 'READONLY'){
               this.items.items[0].disabled = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#cardNumber')[0].disabled = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnEdit')[0].hidden = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnRewrite')[0].hidden  = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnSubmit')[0].hidden  = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnCancel')[0].hidden  = false;
           } else if (config.currentState == 'EDIT'){
               this.items.items[0].disabled = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#cardNumber')[0].disabled = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnEdit')[0].hidden = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnRewrite')[0].hidden  = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnSubmit')[0].hidden  = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnCancel')[0].hidden  = false;
           } else if (config.currentState == 'CREATE'){
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#cardNumber')[0].disabled = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnEdit')[0].hidden = true;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnRewrite')[0].hidden  = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnSubmit')[0].hidden  = false;
               Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#btnCancel')[0].hidden  = false;
           }
            this.owner.doComponentLayout()
           return null;
        },



        createButtons:function (config, form) {
            return [
                {
                    id: 'btnEdit',
                    text:Loyalty.messages['company.edit.fields.edit'],
                    handler:function () {
                        config.currentState =  'EDIT';
                        config.owner.renderingView(config)
                    }
                }  ,
                {
                    xtype:'button',
                    id: 'btnRewrite',
                    text:Loyalty.messages['company.edit.fields.rewrite'],
                    handler:function () {
                        config.currentState =  'READONLY';
                        config.owner.renderingView(config)
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype:'button',
                    id: 'btnSubmit',
                    text:Loyalty.messages['company.edit.fields.submit'],
                    handler:function () {
                        config.currentState =  'CREATE_EDIT';
                        config.owner.renderingView(config)
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype:'button',
                    id: 'btnCancel',
                    text:Loyalty.messages['company.edit.fields.cancel'],
                    handler:function () {
                        if (config.currentState ==  'EDIT' || config.currentState ==  'CREATE_EDIT'){
                            config.currentState =  'READONLY';
                            config.owner.renderingView(config)
                        }
                    }
                }
            ];
        },

        ....
    }
);
```

function renderingView woks good when I call it from constructor. But when it called from the button methods, nothing happens. state of the buttons to change(hidden). 
I think that the problem with repaint

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setVisible` and `setDisabled` methods instead of setting properties in `renderingView`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your config object is undefined when the button handler runs. Do you get an error stack trace in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

the reason was very simple. As soon as I started to use a setVisibled() and setDisabled() instead of disabled and hidden everything worked correctly